# Installing cmu-sphinxbase on AWS EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ruby

I've setup an app on EC2 using Elastic Beanstalk. It's a Ubuntu instance and I'm running a Rails app on it which depends on `sphinxbase` and `pocketsphinx`. I've ssh'd into the EC2 instance to install sphinxbase and its dependencies:

```
sudo yum install autoconf libtool bison swig git
git clone https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase.git
cd sphinxbase/
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
# Libraries have been installed in:
#   /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinxbase
```

After a reboot I navigate to my app's url and I get a Rails error page, looking at the server logs:

```
Could not open library 'libsphinxbase.so': libsphinxbase.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (LoadError)
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:133:in `block in ffi_lib'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pocketsphinx-ruby-0.3.0/lib/pocketsphinx/api/sphinxbase.rb:5:in `<module:Sphinxbase>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pocketsphinx-ruby-0.3.0/lib/pocketsphinx/api/sphinxbase.rb:3:in `<module:API>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pocketsphinx-ruby-0.3.0/lib/pocketsphinx/api/sphinxbase.rb:2:in `<module:Pocketsphinx>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pocketsphinx-ruby-0.3.0/lib/pocketsphinx/api/sphinxbase.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pocketsphinx-ruby-0.3.0/lib/pocketsphinx.rb:6:in `require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pocketsphinx-ruby-0.3.0/lib/pocketsphinx.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pocketsphinx-ruby-0.3.0/lib/pocketsphinx-ruby.rb:1:in `require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pocketsphinx-ruby-0.3.0/lib/pocketsphinx-ruby.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
  /var/app/current/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

So it can't find `libsphinxbase.so`

I'm not sure what to do at this point, and can't find relevant information yet.

Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker pointed me to this blog post, it helped out properly installing cmu sphinx and its dependencies.

http://jrmeyer.github.io/installation/2016/01/09/Installing-CMU-Sphinx-on-Ubuntu.html